# Laravel - ErrorException : Trying to get property 'staff_id' of non-object

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this API:

```
[
  {
    "date_of_birth": "2009-11-21T00:00:00",
    "first_name": "JAGUA",
    "last_name": "KING",
    "staff_id": "44444",
  },
  {
    "date_of_birth": "2005-11-21T00:00:00",
    "first_name": "JACKIE",
    "last_name": "LEE",
    "staff_id": "44444",
  },
]
```

Which I tried to consume and save using Guzzle

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

```
public function handle()
{       
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees', [
     'query' => ['key' => 'dfffgggggffffff']
   ])->getBody();

    $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);        

    foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
    {         
        Employee::updateOrCreate([
            'employee_code' => $clientdata->staff_id,
        ],
        [
            'first_name'                => $clientdata->first_name,
            'last_name'                 => $clientdata->flast_name,
            'date_of_birth'             => Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth'])->toDateString(),
        ]);               
    }           
}
```

when I ran php artisan, I got this error:

> ErrorException  : Trying to get property 'staff_id' of non-object

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: try using the dd() function (dump and die) on your result to see if the path to your data is what you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter of `json_decode()` is whether it should return associative or not. You are setting it to true and there it will return an `array`.

This approach is the correct one, when you use it as an object.

```
$clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents());
```

And change the array access to be used as object.

```
$clientdata['date_of_birth']
```

Should be.

```
$clientdata->date_of_birth;
```